# Polynomial Calculator using Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm working on a polynomial calculator project and I'm working on the first part. Polynomials will be represented in a specific format where two polynomials are a sequence of integers representing the coefficients and exponents. Here's an example.

```
4 3 -2 2 6 1
6 3 5 2 3 1
```

Polynomial 1 = `4x^3 - 2x^2 + 6x` and Polynomial 2 = `6x^3 + 5x^2 + 3x`
I'm supposed to use Linked List to implement this. 
Here's my `class Node` code:

```
class Node {
    int coef;
    int power;
    Node next;
    public Node(int coef, int power) {
        this.coef = coef;
        this.power = power;
    }
}
```

How do I efficiently separate the coefficients and the exponents and add to the Linked List?
Here's my code for pushing a new Polynomial node:

```
void addPoly(int coef, int pow) {
    Node newNode = new Node(coef, pow);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        head.next = null;
    } else {
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks good to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea for me to remove all white-space first, then inside a for loop, addPoly() where the first coefficient is chartAt(0) and the next coeffiecient would be 0+2 and so on (The same with exponents but charAt(1))?

Comment: @C0DeX do you really get the `int`s with `charAt`? This will not work if you have negative values like your example

Comment: If your list is always in order you can loop backwards (begin at ^1) so you don't always have to iterate through your list's end.

Comment: Stripping whitespace would work fine if all numbers were single digit.  But if you have something like `13 12 11 10`, it wouldn't be distinguishable from `1 3 1 2 1 1 1 0`

Comment: I'm using a Scanner now. I'm using .next() to get the first int, which is the coefficient. Instead of creating a bunch of .next() creating a for loop might work best right? I already tried but I don't think I'm implementing it correctly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for advice on how to improve working code, rather than fixing broken code. This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your input and then convert each resulting string to an integer. If the power is always in decreasing order you loop backwards to reduce code complexity.

```
String s = "4 3 -2 2 6 1";
int[] values = Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
    .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
    .toArray();
assert values.length % 2 == 0;
for (int i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i = i - 2) {
    int coeff = values[i - 1];
    int power = values[i];
    addPoly(coeff, power);
}
```

`addPoly` can be reduced to

```
void addPoly(int coeff, int power) {
    Node node = new Node(coeff, power);
    node.next = head;
    head = node;
}
```

At the first iteration `head` is `null` so the first node becomes the end of the list. Each next step is the predecessor. So the `head` is it's `next`. Last but not least the new node becomes the next `head`.

Comment: head should be the first element, not the last.

Answer (score 0):

Java-9 solution, using regex [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with two capture groups and a [MatchResults stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--):

```
String input = "4 3 -2 2 6 1";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s+(-?\\d+)");
// add all the polynomials to myList
p.matcher(input).results().forEach(m -> myList.addPoly(m.group(1), m.group(2));
```